# Why Mysql explain use index for following SQL statement instead of range

Tags: mysql

I have a table:

```
create table user (

id int primary key,

name varchar(20)

)engine=innodb;

insert into user values(1,'lily');

insert into user values(2,'tom');

insert into user values(3,'bob');

insert into user values(4,'jimi');

insert into user values(5,'moth');
```

If I run

```
explain select * from user where id in (1,2,3)
```

or

```
explain select name from user where id in (1,2,3)
```

Mysql shows that **the type is range**,
but when run:

```
 explain select id from user where id in (1,2,3)
```

Mysql shows that **the type is index**.
**So why is there such a difference?**

Comment: I'm struggling to spot the difference between these queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The critical thing to realize here is that for such a small table MySQL may not choose to use *any* index, despite there being an index which might help the query plan execute faster.  Actually, both of the queries you showed should be sargable, and MySQL should be able to use the clustered index on the `id` primary key.  Try adding substantially more data, and MySQL would likely use an index scan to satisfy the query.

Comment: Indeed, as you said, I added a lot of data to the table to verify this. Thank you